# PHP imap_open fails via Apache with "no such host" but works at command line

Tags: php, email

I am using PHP 5.3.10 on CentOS 5.8.  PHP has been built from source with this config:

```
./configure --enable-gd-native-ttf --enable-mbstring \
  --enable-sockets --with-bz2 --with-curl --with-gd --with-mcrypt \
  --with-mysql --with-mhash --with-mysqli --with-openssl --with-pdo-mysql \
  --with-pear --with-pcre-regex --with-xsl --with-zlib --with-libdir=/lib64 \
  --with-imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs
```

I am positive there are no other versions of PHP on the system, and I've confirmed that through the browser and CLI that the imap extension is available.

This issue is affecting a CMS I'm using, but to test I used a simple PHP script, which is:

```
<?php
error_reporting(15);

$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$mailserver = "{pop.gmail.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";

$link = imap_open($mailserver, $username, $password, NULL, 1);
print_r(imap_errors());

$headers = imap_headers($link);
print_r($headers);
?>
```

When I run this at the command line I get the expected output which is no error messages and a list of the messages in the inbox.

When I point a browser to the test script I get:

```
Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {pop.gmail.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in test.php on line 9
Array ( [0] => No such host as pop.gmail.com )
```

and then additional warnings as imap_headers fails.

Clearly the imap extension is available via Apache and CLI, and this shouldn't be a firewall or DNS issue as it does work from the CLI.  I can also telnet to the mail server.

I am using the default php.ini-development file (a copy is [here](http://pastebin.com/XbZZHXeq)) and confirmed with phpinfo() and php -i that it's in use by both environments.

Does anyone have any ideas why imap_open would come back with "no such host as..." through Apache but not at the command line?

edit:

I am using libc-client and libc-client-devel version 2004g-2.2.1 and httpd 2.2.3-63.el5.centos.1 from the stock CentOS yum repos

Comment: I have run into issues where a fqdn did not resolve so I added it to localhosts, or fixed my dns, and it worked from CLI but not through apache. But after restarting apache, things worked as expected, so try restarting and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Mike, I think you're on the right track.  A call to gethostbyaddr('pop.gmail.com') works via CLI and fails through the browser.  Restarting Apache has not helped though.  I also restarted nscd.

Comment: Oh no.. I forgot that Apache is using mod_chroot which is going to block the DNS lookup.  There's a workaround and I'll post that once it works.

Comment: Also, check to see if you have SELinux enabled. It may be blocking httpd access as well.

Comment: I had to add LoadFile /lib64/libnss_dns.so.2 to my httpd.conf which fixed the issue.  Unfortunately mod_chroot is now interfering with the SSL portion of the request, but that's a different issue.  Thank you Mike for pointing me towards DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that Apache was using mod_chroot and apparently access to the library providing DNS was blocked.  I had to add `LoadFile /lib64/libnss_dns.so.2` to my httpd.conf, thanks to [this page](http://core.segfault.pl/~hobbit/mod_chroot/caveats.html).